# Writing into Excel file using PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

I have a php code that is triggered whenever a user clicks a determined button. That code basically creates a new directory and a new Excel File inside that same dir. My goal is to write into that excel file. I have the following code (which is not working, btw):

```
$filename = 'moldes/VLMOLDES_'.$id.'/Orcamento161.xlsm';
$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($filename);
$worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$worksheet->getCell('A18')->setValue('3');
```

Everything but writing in the file is working as expected. When I click the button, it opens a blank page but nothing happens! I've tried a lot of different ways but I'm a noob in phpSpreadSheets. How can I write in a specific cell in that file?

Comment: In what way is it not working? Not Working is not really helpful if you want us to help

Comment: Did you save the amended spreadsheet before looking for the chnage?

Comment: Well, I'm not really into this phpSpreadsheet. All I did was, in my "moldes" directory, add a main file called "Orcamentos". Everytime a user clicks a button, it calls two php functions: mkdir (to create a dir inside that /moldes) and copy (to copy the original "Orçamentos" and paste it into the new dir). After that, I use that code that I put on the question and every time I click the button, a blank page comes and that is just it. I go check the file and the cell just ain't modified!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the following - you need to save the file at the end of your code or the changes won't be reflected in the file.

```
$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, "Xlsx");
$writer->save('moldes/VLMOLDES_'.$id.'/Orcamento161.xlsm');
```

Also, it may be preferred to use:

```
$worksheet->setCellValue('A18', '3');
```